# Maintain UITableViewCell background color when going into edit mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have set background colors for all my UITableViewCells. However, when I click my UIBarButtonItem "edit", the delete and the draggable icons distort the background color, making white background behind them. Is there any way around this? I can show code if necessary, but this seems like a pretty straightforward question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the `uitableviewcells` in the editing mode.  Try setting the background color for your tableViewCells again in

```
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
if(editing)
{
  // set background color
}

else {
}
```

If needed, try setting your background color as your property so that you can set it up here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I had to alloc/init my background view, I thought that came with the tableViewCell. The code that worked for me was:
    `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]].backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
            [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]].backgroundView.backgroundColor = [[cellArray objectAtIndex:i] color];`

Everything worked after that.

Comment: Thank you Mason. I've had the exact same problem and I have been banging my head against it for the past several hours. Finally your insights about initializing backgroundView solved my problem.

Comment: I had the same issue for such a long time and initializing the backgroundView made all the difference!

Answer (score 8):

The background color of a table cell is usually set like this:

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This works fine. However, when an object of class UITableViewCell is created, by default it does not have a backgroundView, it is nil. The developer needs to create the backgroundView when needed. So depending on the particular situation you need to do something like:

```
if (cell.backgroundView == nil) {
  cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```